# Prove there is no function analytic in $\{ |z|<2 \}$ such that $f(0) = 1, f(1) = f(-1) = 0$ and $|f(z)| \le |z| +1$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I want to prove that there is no function $f$ that:

Is analytic in $\{ |z|<2 \}$.

$f(0) = 1, f(1) = f(-1) = 0$

$|f(z)| \le |z| +1$ for all $z$.

It seems logical to think about using the maximum modulus principle somehow. However, there are two problems. I don't know that on the boundary, for example on $|z| < 1$, the function doesn't get a maximum since I am given only two points. Moreover, I can't use $\frac {1}{f}$ since the inequality is on the wrong side. I don't even know that $\frac {1}{f}$ is analytic.

Actually, I don't see how the information that is given helps me here.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(1) = f(-1) = 0$ implies that
$$
 g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^2-1}
$$
has only removable singularities and can be extended to a
 holomorphic function in  $\{ |z|<2 \}$. For $|z| \le r$ with $1 < r < 2$ we have
$$
|g(z)| \le \max_{|w|=r} |g(w)| \le \frac{r+1}{r^2-1}
$$
and for $r \to 2$ it follows that
$$ 
|g(z)| \le \frac{2+1}{2^2-1} = 1
$$
for all $z$. Since $|g(0)| = |f(0)| = 1$, the maximum modulus principle implies that $g$ is constant, and consequently 
$$
 f(z) = 1- z^2 
$$
for all $z$.

But then the condition $|f(z)| \le |z| +1$ is violated, e.g. for $z = iy$ with $1 < y < 2$:
$$
 |f(iy) | =  1 + y^2  > 1 + y =  |iy| +1 \, .
$$

Comment: For $z = 3i/2$ ?

Comment: @Jakobian: You are right, $f(2i)$ is not defined – thanks.

Comment: Why does the fact that g(0)=-1 imply that g is constant?

Comment: @Moko19: We have that $|g(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$, and $|g(0)|=1$. In other words: $|g| $ has a maximum at $z=0$. Then the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) implies that $g$ is constant.

Comment: wow this is a pretty neat answer. I doesn't seem trivial to use $\frac {f(z)}{z^2-1}$

Comment: @GabiG: Actually it resembles the proof of the Schwarz lemma: There you have $f(0)=0$ and then $f(z)/z$ is considered.

Comment: You are right. I think you can even prove this exercise using Schwarz's lemma in some way.